# A theorem comprising Limit points and Neighborhood.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Theorem : If $p$ is a limit point of a set $E$, then every Neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $E$.

Proof: Suppose there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ which contains only a finite number of points of $E$.  Let $q_{1},q_{2},...,q_{n}$ be those points of $N_{r}(p) \cup E$, which are distinct from $p$, and put $r = min_{1 ≤ m ≤ n}d(p,q_{m})$.

Then, $N_{r}(P) \cap E = {p}$ or it's empty. This implies that $p$ is not a limit point of $E$. A contradiction. $\blacksquare$

(Q1) Why are we defining radius $r$ in terms of a metric?
(Q2) How did we arrive at the conclusion that $N_{r}(P) \cap E = {p}$? Is it related to the choice of r here?

I tried to write the definition for $N_{r}(p)$, taking $r = min(d(p,q_{m}))$ but *for me* it really isn't making any sense! Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are the first three paragraphs quoted from a text? If so, what text is that?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. We are working on a metric space, which has a metric $d$. Are you suggesting that the proof should not use $d$ *at all*?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It does seem like this shouldn’t need metric, just $T_1$ Should do it,, since you can intersect finitely many neighborhoods to get one not containing any of the points.  Or am I forgetting some subtlety in the definitions for general case?

Comment: @MW Are you assuming that the OP knows what a $T_1$ topological space is? I think that it is far more likely that the OP is working only in the context of metric spaces.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It's from Walter Rudin's, Principles of Mathematical analysis.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos fair point.  I just thought that might be one plausible reason for OP to wonder why using the metric.  But I didn’t totally follow the question’s phrasing anyway so who knows?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I wanted to ask that 'why' are we defining r in terms of d(p,q(m))? Is it because it will help us in the proof? I apologise if I'm asking the obvious but i'm still learning about proofs so it's kind of a bouncer to me.

Comment: Uh,  My apologies for making the question ambiguous.

Comment: We are working with a metric $d$ and we want to prove something about a point $p$ assuming that we know a certain thing about certain points $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n$. *What else* could we possibly use, in your opinion?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos uh, i get that- But please look at my second question. I thought that *maybe* defining r in terms of a metric is playing a role here in showing that the intersection between N and E = {p}. But if that's not the case then how is that r is relevant. Again, i apologise if am asking the obvious, i'm still a novice in proofs. :)

Comment: My comment was about the first question, not about the second one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos geez, i know that- but first question is indeed related to the second. My previous comment.

Comment: There are two errors in the proof of the theorem: when you wrote $\color{blue}{N_r(P)}\color{red}\cup E$, it should be $\color{blue}N\color{red}{\cap}E$.

Comment: The final sentence is wrong. It should be $N\cap N_r(p)\cap E$ rather than just $N_r(p)\cap E$.

Comment: Are you worried about the fact that in Definition 2.18(a), the name $r$ is used for the radius of a neighborhood, but in the proof of Theorem 2.20, the name $r$ is assigned to the minimum of a set of distances? I wonder if that's why you wrote $N_r(p)$ instead of $N$ (as it appears in the text) in your proof.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Rudin uses *neighborhood* for “open ball,” so $N_r(p) \subseteq N$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

(1) We are trying to derive a contradiction - our goal is to find a neighborhood of $p$ that does not intersect $E$ at any point other than (possibly) itself. If there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ that intersects $A$ only at finitely many points, then we may enumerate them $\{ q_1, \dots, q_n \}$. For each of these points, we find a neighborhood of $p$ that does not contain it. This is certainly possible in metric spaces, where we can just take $B_d (p, d (p, q_k))$; clearly, $d (p, q_k) = r_k$ is not less than $r_k$, so $q_k \notin B_d (p, d (p, q_k))$. Since finite intersections of open sets are open, we have that

$$B_d (p, \min_{1 \le k \le n} d (p, q_k)) = \bigcap_{k = 1}^n B_d (p, d (p, q_k))$$

is a neighborhood of $p$, and it obviously does not contain any $q_k$.

(Note that this can be derived even if $X$ is not a metric space; we just require that for any two distinct points $x_1 \ne x_2 \in X$ that we can find a neighborhood of one not containing the other. As mentioned in the comments, such spaces are called "T1".)

(2) Take two cases: either $p \in E$, or $p \notin E$. In the former case, the basis element $B_d (p, \min_{1 \le k \le n} d (p, q_k))$ does intersect $E$, but *only* at $p$ (by construction). In the latter case, that basis element does not intersect $E$ at all. This shows $p$ is not a limit point of $E$.